# How to use node-mssql query SQL Server Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]?

Tags: node.js, sql-server, express, node-mssql

```
const request = new sql.Request(transaction)
request.query('select * from TB_USER', (err, result) => {
    if (err) {                            
        res.send(err);
        transaction.rollback(err => {
            console.log("Transaction RolledBack.")
        })
    }
    else{
        res.status(200).json({"result":result.recordsets})
        transaction.commit(err => {
            console.log("Transaction committed.")
        })                        
    }

})
const request1 = new sql.Request(transaction)
request1.query('select * from TB_USER', (err, result) => {
    if (err) {                            
        res.send(err);
        transaction.rollback(err => {
            console.log("Transaction RolledBack.")
        })
    }
    else{
        res.status(200).json({"result":result.recordsets})
        transaction.commit(err => {
            console.log("Transaction committed.")
        })                        
    }

})
```

Error:

> _http_outgoing.js:536
> throw new ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT('set');
> ^
>
> Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent
> to the client
>
> at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:536:11)
> at ServerResponse.header (A:\register-api\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:771:10)
> at ServerResponse.send (A:\register-api\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:170:12)
> at ServerResponse.json (A:\register-api\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:267:15)
> at A:\register-api\src\utils\functions\updateCust.js:15:33
> at A:\register-api\node_modules\mssql\lib\base\request.js:446:9
> at Request.userCallback (A:\register-api\node_modules\mssql\lib\tedious\request.js:479:15)
> at Request.callback (A:\register-api\node_modules\tedious\lib\request.js:206:14)
> at Parser.onEndOfMessage (A:\register-api\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:2902:22)
> at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:420:28) {   code: 'ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT' } [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...

Comment: You use `res.status(200).json` twice in one request. One request, one response -- this is not specific to SQL Server in any way. If you want to combine result sets, you must do so before sending a response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One request doesn't accept two `res`,

1. So we used `return` keyword before `res.send()` ,
   So It won't go for second `res` in the code.
2. Always put statement/code which return something after your sepcific code run, So I changed position of `transaction.commit()` and put it before `return res.send()`.

```
if (err) {
  transaction.rollback((err) => {
    console.log("Transaction RolledBack.");
  });
  return res.send(err);
} else {
  transaction.commit(() => {
    console.log("Transaction committed.");
  });
  return res.status(200).json({ result: result.recordsets });
}
```